# Steps to create instance, parameter file , password file and database

Tags: oracle

_Hi everybody 
_i wanna all steps to create instance, parameter file , password file and database 
_manually in oracle 10g 
_i hope from all to help me

Comment: This question doesn't intimate anything that you've tried, why what you're doing isn't working, nor how we can help you fix that and make it work for you. Please help us help you and tell us what we can do for you that you weren't able to do on your own. This is not a site for generating guides of steps, this is a site where experts help others fix the problems they are having.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle configuration is very complex and someone could easily write dozens of pages of documentation describing the things you are asking about.  Try to find a tutorial or (better yet) an experienced DBA to help you get started.

Short of that, find a good book on Oracle database administration.  One of the best DBA books I've read is [Pro Oracle Database Administration](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430229705) by Darl Kuhn. Chapter 2 covers almost everything you are asking about.

Once do get started, come back here if you're still having trouble and post **specific error messages**. You'll have a much better chance of getting some useful assistance that way.